# Multiple ESP8266-12E's with multiple touch sensors

Tags: arduino, esp8266, touch

I'm looking for some advice, and I'm not sure I'm barking up the right tree by using ESP8266 NodeMCU CP2102 ESP-12E's.

I am currently using Arduino IDE to program the 8266's. I have two 8266's that I want to use for my cabinet lighting. I have different strands of 2811/2812 strands to try (RGB, RGBW and just W), but all I want to use is white light. I have no desire to have a web page where I can control the color. I want them to communicate to turn lights on an off based on touch sensor inputs. (I use relays to control the power to the strips.)

Module #1 will have two strings of LED's as well as two touch sensor inputs. (either sensor will control both strings.)

Module #2 will have one string of LED's as well as one touch sensor input.

[image: ESP Diagram]

Is it possible to have these modules send commands to each other that basically trigger a status check and command? Is Arduino IDE the right environment to be using, or should I be looking at Visual Studio/Platform IO  - It seems that different LED libraries want you to use different IDE's?

The basic touch switch code I am using is this: (It turns the LED's on at first power up, which I don't like. But changing the initial states around hasn't fixed that. Not sure why.)

```
const int relay = 5;
const int TOUCH_BUTTON_PIN = 16;
int switchStatus;
int switchStatusLast = LOW;
int RelayStatus = LOW; 


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TOUCH_BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  
}

void loop() 
{
  // Read the state of the capacitive touch board
  switchStatus = digitalRead(TOUCH_BUTTON_PIN);
 
  // If a touch is detected, turn on the LED
  if (switchStatus != switchStatusLast) 
  {
    if (switchStatus == HIGH && switchStatusLast == LOW) RelayStatus = ! RelayStatus;
      digitalWrite(relay, RelayStatus);
      switchStatus = switchStatusLast;
  } 
  
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually asking. If your question is *“Is it possible to have these modules send commands to each other that basically trigger a status check and command?”* the answer is yes, but there are multiple ways to achieve this. You can make use of a platform like Tasmota or ESPHome or roll your own, using an MQTT broker on a Raspberry Pi (for example).

Comment: A mqtt client/server is one way. The other is get/post commands but that's essentially doing a web page like setup.

Comment: I was hoping to come up with something more direct and standalone.  I am currently looking at this and trying to figure out how to send data back and forth.  https://blog.zairza.in/esp8266-to-esp8266-communication-without-a-router-fe9642b93292

Comment: Well your using a wifi based microcontroller which means the ip stack is the intended way. You could ignore that by using Bluetooth modules or using rf 433mhz or similar radios.

Comment: Look into the 8266's ESP-NOW feature; a way to use the radio w/o wifi. It's a little confusing on the terms at first, but it works VERY well. With wifi, you can also just code a simple http API (ala HelloServer) on the led switcher, eg `/set/?A=1`, then use the HTTPClient example on the button ESP to GET that api url; static IPs recommended, but no need for a broker, internet, port settings, or any other un-needed complication.